# How to center this div I have already done justify-content: center; align-items: center. Still the container div is not getting centered

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

[The container is not stack at the center of the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Z9E.png)
HTML code:-

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./images/image-qr-code.png" alt="qrcode">
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      <h2>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h2>
      <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS code:-

```
.container{
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I tried to move the container div to the center but it is not getting stack at the center

Comment: If you want the content of body to be at the center of body then it's body that needs the flex etc.

Comment: And the body needs a height higher than fit-content (auto).

Answer (score 0):

As you want the container in the center you need to wrap that div in the other div and make it flex and justify-content:center

```
<style>
  .container {
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .main-div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="main-div">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="./images/image-qr-code.png" alt="qrcode">
      </div>
      <div class="heading">
        <h2>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h2>
        <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the margin property to auto may help to resolve your issue.

```css
.container{
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./images/image-qr-code.png" alt="qrcode">
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
      <h2>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h2>
      <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```